# Behavior of a map insertion with operator[] when the right side of the following assignation contains a call to size

Tags: c++, c++11

Assuming a `std::map<T, std::size_t>`, what is the result of the insertion below, assuming `x` does not exist yet ? unspecified, undefined behavior or well known result ?

```
map[x] = map.size();
```

I am lacking of imagination to summarize the question in the title, if someone has a better idea for it, please update, thanks.

To my comprehension of c++, the sequence point is only set at the `;`, so a compiler can do whatever he wants and it should be unspecified behavior, but would appreciate if someone can pin point the standard quote on it.

Comment: You basically need someone to do one of those long sequenced-before-after-in-whatever answers. Or can't you find a general-purpose one that tells you what happens on the LHS vs RHS of an `op=` for a class type w.r.t. evaluation order?

Comment: Hint: first the rhs is evaluated, then it is assigned to the lhs.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: You would need to prove that with standard language in order to be convincing, because it's often not that simple at all. When is the LHS evaluated? That's what you want to be asking.

Comment: The `=` is the built-in operator, and the value computations of the two sides of it are unsequenced - except that both are function calls, so they are indeterminately sequenced instead. Unspecified result - the `size()` can happen either before or after the element is inserted.

Comment: Dupe is close enough IMO

Comment: I agree on the duplicate

Comment: NOte that "sequence point" is deprecated in favor of 'sequenced before' and 'sequenced after'. And "assignation" is the most creative way I've heard of describing "assignment"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are not going to edit the question and then open it back again for the hat, are you?

Comment: @Jefffrey Don't give me ideas ;p